# matplotlib failed to plot in a thread except the first time

Tags: python, multithreading, matplotlib

I have the following code that plots a changing curve using matplotlib in a thread, and it seems I can only plot it once, the second time I start a new thread for the same function, matplotlib just plot an empty figure and hangs up.

code attached

```
import threading
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib
# matplotlib.use('')

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time


plt.ion()
running = False  # if running false, thread automatically ends

def drawing():
    print("start drawing")
    data = np.arange(100)
    fig, axes = plt.subplots()
    line, = axes.plot(data)
    while running:
        data = np.roll(data, 1)
        line.set_ydata(data)
        # plt.draw()
        fig.canvas.flush_events()
        time.sleep(0.1)

    print("stop drawing")

def run_drawing():
    global running
    while 1:
        if running:
            c = input("press 'q' to quit or enter to STOP drawing: ")
        else:
            c = input("press 'q' to quit or enter to START drawing: ")

        if c == 'q':
            if running:
                running = False
            break
        else:
            if not running:
                t1 = threading.Thread(target=drawing)
                running = True
                t1.start()
            else:
                running = False


if __name__ == '__main__':
    run_drawing()
```

and enclosed are two images to show what I mean by matplotlib figure hanging up. the second time the thread is actually running , 'cus if I put print out in the thread function's while loop, the data is changing.

I would like to know why is that and is there a way to resolve this issue?
[image: first time thread]
[image: second time thread]

Comment: Why not turn on interactive mode using `plt.ion()`?

Comment: @James it is turned on at the very beginning of the code `plt.ion()`